# Django application migration

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I have a class Tweet, and I am trying to add User model to it such that user can have many tweets, but a tweet only belongs to a user.

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
  context = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

when I try to migrate i get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Anonymous'
```

I had a `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="anonymous")`

but I removed it and error still presists

Comment: Removing it will not help, since it is already in the *migration* file. You thus need to remove the migration file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing it will not help, since it is already in the *migration* file. You thus need to remove the migration file as well.

If you want to use a `User` with *username* `anonymous`, then you can use a callable for that:

```
from django.conf import settings

def get_anonymous():
    if hasattr(get_anonymous, 'result'):
        return get_anonymous.result
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
    result = get_anonymous.result = User.objects.get(username='Anonymous')
    return result

class Tweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=get_anonymous
    )
    context = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

But this thus only works in case there is a `User` record with `username='Anonymous'`. If there is no such record, one often makes use of `NULL` to denote a missing user, so:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Tweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
    context = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).